# Transform Scapy Packet to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, scapy, pcap

I am writing a Python Backend for a Pcap analysis Tool.
The communication with the (electron) Frontend works via zerorpc.
Now I need to send a list of Packets from the pcap to the Frontend and therefore I need to format them as a JSON object.
I have been trying many different things and I have been searching the web for hours, but I did not find a single working solution.

So my question is:
How can I transform a list of Scapy Packets to a JSON Object?

Greetings
NIoSaT

Comment: Does the frontend need all fields from packets?

Comment: The Idea is to compare two Pcap Files, so yeah the more header Fields are available to the frontend the better.

Comment: any solution here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting JSON content from a packet using Scapy with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541272/getting-json-content-from-a-packet-using-scapy-with-python)